# Why am I getting a 404 for my LESS file on my Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, less, azure-web-app-service

Ok, so... famous saying... this works locally, but not when I deploy.

I recently switched to using Less.js so that I could dynamically change my less variables with Javascript. Again, locally this works like a champ.

In my header I have it referenced:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="~/Content/main.less" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js"></script>
```

When I use Visual Studio to deploy this to my Azure App Service I get a 404 on the less file and it all breaks.

I FTP'd into my server and the file is indeed there. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl2xL.png

I double checked to make sure that my properties for the less file are right. I have the build action set to Content and Copy if Newer. https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9iRN.png

No matter what I do, if I go looking for that main.less file the azure server returns a 404.

As an FYI, the site is a ASP.Net MVC 5 website. I am using bundling, but only for external css like JQueryUI. I have removed the bundling of my CSS to work with the new stuff.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to just have your editor pre-compile your less files into CSS, and serve those instead.

Comment: I was doing that with bundling, but I can't precompile and dynamically change my LESS variables... unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! After a bunch of attempts and searches I finally found a related error and found my solution.

This poor gentleman was having an issue serving up JSON files ([angular2 app, http request for file json file, 404 on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811088/angular2-app-http-request-for-file-json-file-404-on-azure)) and that made me think I had the same problem.

Eureka! I needed to update my web.config to let it serve LESS files.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent>
<system.webServer>
```

Hope this helps someone else who runs into the same issue.